# can we also do mobile web app with PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

As for as I know with PhoneGap, we can generate Platform specific native apps. Is it possible to develop/convert phoneGap build to some web app, just in case my phoneGap developed iOS build got rejected by iPhone market. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap apps are simply your web assets (HTML/JS/CSS) packaged as native apps and rendered in a very specific browser view. Your code is not converted into platform specific bits. Your files inside www are in fact your web app (albeit rendered as file:// within PhoneGap as opposed to http:// in a browser). If you don't invoke any PhoneGap plugins, this should be straight forward.